# Using XSLT 1.0 apply-templates only on certain attribute values

Tags: xslt, conditional-statements, xslt-1.0, apply-templates

I'm trying to stay away from a procedural approach with this solution and I'm not sure that's possible.

Here's my XML:

```
<countData>
<count countId="37" name="Data Response 1">
    <year yearId="2013">
        <month monthId="5">
            <day dayId="23" countVal="6092"/>
            <day dayId="24" countVal="6238"/>
            <day dayId="27" countVal="6324"/>
            <day dayId="28" countVal="6328"/>
            <day dayId="29" countVal="3164"/>
        </month>
            <day dayId="23" countVal="7000"/>
            <day dayId="24" countVal="7000"/>
            <day dayId="27" countVal="7000"/>
            <day dayId="28" countVal="7000"/>
            <day dayId="29" countVal="7000"/>
        </month>
    </year>
</count>
<count countId="39" name="Data Response 2">
    <year yearId="2013">
        <month monthId="5">
            <day dayId="23" countVal="675"/>
            <day dayId="24" countVal="709"/>
            <day dayId="27" countVal="754"/>
            <day dayId="28" countVal="731"/>
            <day dayId="29" countVal="377"/>
        </month>
    </year>
</count>
```

I want to apply-templates (in this example) for all count/@countIds that are 37 or 39. Here's where I am:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:apply-templates mode="TimeFrame"/>

</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="TimeFrame">

    <xsl:if test="count[@countId=37] or count[@countId=39]">
        <magic>Only hitting this once for countId 37</magic>
    </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

I'm going to have quite a few of these templates with "modes" since I'm processing the same response a multitude of different ways.

Not sure how I'm missing the "range" match and only getting 1.

I'm sure it has to do with my "procedural mind". :)

Any help on this would be great!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main template, `<xsl:template match="/">`, runs only once - namely for the `<countData>` element.

Which means that you either forgot to recurse:

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="TimeFrame">

    <xsl:if test="count[@countId=37] or count[@countId=39]">
        <magic>Only hitting this once for countId 37</magic>
    </xsl:if>

    <xsl:apply-templates mode="TimeFrame"/> <!-- ! -->

</xsl:template>
```

...or you failed to set the right context for the the main template:

```
<xsl:template match="/countData"><!-- ! -->

    <xsl:apply-templates mode="TimeFrame"/>

</xsl:template>

<!-- or, alternatively -->

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:apply-templates select="countData/*" mode="TimeFrame"/>

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: My problem is that I'm trying to evaluate the "countId" value BEFORE I start to spin through the child nodes. The addition of the apply-templates select = "*" in the template mode="TimeFrame" forces the recursion to happen in those children. I really just want to do a "match" on the "countIDs" that are values of x,y,z and THEN process their child nodes.

Comment: Actually, I had a typo after I attempted to take your advice. This works exactly like I wanted it. Thanks so much!